# Yii Booster TbTotalSumColumn formatted as currency

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii Booster, and one of the widgets is TbTotalSumColumn.

When it renders the total in the footer, it uses the following code:

```
echo $this->totalValue? $this->evaluateExpression($this->totalValue, array('total'=>$this->total)) : $this->grid->getFormatter()->format($this->total, $this->type);
```

I have used CFormatter and created a 'currency' type, I have applied the formatting directly in the 'value' attribute, I have gone into the widget and applied the currency formatter there. It seems no matter what I do, I can only get either the values in the column to be formatted as currency, or the footer, never both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a new class file in the components folder called TbTotalColumnCurrency.php.  Then I call TbTotalSumColumnCurrency in my TbExtendedGridView code.

```
Yii::import('bootstrap.widgets.TbTotalSumColumn');

class TbTotalSumColumnCurrency extends TbTotalSumColumn
{
    protected function renderFooterCellContent()
    {
        if(is_null($this->total))
            return parent::renderFooterCellContent();

        echo $this->totalValue? $this->evaluateExpression($this->totalValue, array('total'=>number_format($this->total), 2, '.', '')) : $this->grid->getFormatter()->format(number_format($this->total, 2, '.', ''), $this->type);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

```
array(
    'name'=>'Total',
    'type'=>'text',
    'value'=>'number_format($data->price*$data->quantity, 2, \'.\', \'\')',
    'class'=>'TbTotalSumColumnCurrency'
),
```

Comment: Correction, I put that new file in my components folder.  Sorry :)

Comment: Haha awesome, I came to this very same solution on my own and never saw your answer. Thanks man.

Comment: No worries, just watch where you use the TbTotalSumColumn at, for whatever reason right now it's not very responsive friendly.  It looks hideous on a mobile device.  Trying to find a way to hide it when the screen shrinks, but no luck yet.

Comment: Luckily my app I am using it on isn't really suitable for a mobile app anyway so I haven't had to worry about this. Good Luck though. And thanks again.